# Load Android tabhost fullscreen

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I'm working on an Android `TabWidget` application. Once I click a tab button, the content of it should load in full-screen not as a tab item, I checked to set the flag for full-screen and also theme in manifest, but didn't work either,

```
// Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );

// Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sad that you want tab to load in full screen , it means that it must be an Activity. so why you don't opening it like Activity? I don't think that some part of `TabWidget` can showing full screen , because `TabWidget` will loose his specification. I mean `TabWidget` is for Tabs , but you want open some tab like Activity

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan